# Spring Security not catching login failures in ApplicationListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 3.2.5.RELEASE and am having difficulty catching failed login attempts. I currently have an `ApplicationListener` configured as follows:

```
@Component
public class MyApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener<AbstractAuthenticationEvent> {

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyApplicationListener);

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AbstractAuthenticationEvent abstractAuthenticationEvent) {

        if (abstractAuthenticationEvent instanceof AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent) {

            logger.warn("Detected an invalid login");

        } else if (abstractAuthenticationEvent instanceof AuthenticationSuccessEvent) {

            logger.info("A user logged in successfully");
        }
    }
}
```

If a user logs in successfully I can see the success message as expected. However, if a user supplies a bad password etc. the failure message never shows.

I changed the listener so it logs all `ApplicationEvent` as below:

```
@Component
public class MyApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyApplicationListener);

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent applicationEvent) {

        logger.info("Got an event of type {}", applicationEvent.getClass());
    }
}
```

However the only security-related events that are logged are of type `org.springframework.security.authentication.event.InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent`. A failed login does not trigger any events. I would appreciate any pointers, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe is a bit late, but i got the same problem and solve it this way:

In your configureGlobal method:
           `auth.authenticationEventPublisher(defaultAuthenticationEventPublisher());`

Dont forget to declare the DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher as a Bean

```
@Bean
public DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher defaultAuthenticationEventPublisher(){
    return new DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher();
}
```

More info here:
[Why the event AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent is never triggered in spring security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782913/why-the-event-abstractauthenticationfailureevent-is-never-triggered-in-spring-se)