# Spring AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent is not working. When authentication is Failed

Tags: java, spring-security

Trying to trigger authentication failed event. But it was not triggered

```
@EventListener
    public void authFailedEventListener(AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent authenticationFailureEvent) {
        // code for logging audit
        if(authenticationFailureEvent instanceof AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent) { System.out.print(true);
    }else {
        System.out.print(false);
        
    }
        System.out.println(authenticationFailureEvent);
        //System.out.println("login failed for -->"+authenticationFailureEvent.getAuthentication().getPrincipal());
        System.out.print("Event Catched for Failed");
    }
```

Config class

```
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        try {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthentication);
        auth.authenticationEventPublisher(new DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher));
        }catch(OAuth2Exception ex) {
            throw new CustomOauthException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the event AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent is never triggered in spring security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782913/why-the-event-abstractauthenticationfailureevent-is-never-triggered-in-spring-se)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure `DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher` like the following

```
@Bean
DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher defaultAuthenticationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
     return new DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher);
  }
```

and use it in your authentication manager like

```
  @Autowired
  DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher defaultAuthenticationEventPublisher;
  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationEventPublisher(defaultAuthenticationEventPublisher);
  }
```

The test I did:

**config class**

```
@Configuration
public class ProjectConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().httpBasic();
  }

  @Autowired
  DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher defaultAuthenticationEventPublisher;

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
        .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    auth.authenticationEventPublisher(defaultAuthenticationEventPublisher);
  }

  @Override
  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  @Bean
  DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher defaultAuthenticationEventPublisher(
      ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
    return new DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher);
  }
}
```

and the listener class:

```
@Component
public class GlobalEventsHandlers {

  @EventListener
  public void authFailedEventListener(
      AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent authenticationFailureEvent) {
    // code for logging audit
    if (authenticationFailureEvent instanceof AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent) {
      System.out.println("authenticationFailureEvent");
    } else {
      System.out.println("not authenticationFailureEvent");

    }
    System.out.println(authenticationFailureEvent);
    //System.out.println("login failed for -->"+authenticationFailureEvent.getAuthentication().getPrincipal());
    System.out.println("Event Catched for Failed");
  }

  @EventListener
  public void authSuccessEventListener(AuthenticationSuccessEvent authenticationSuccessEvent) {
    // code for logging audit
    if (authenticationSuccessEvent instanceof AuthenticationSuccessEvent) {
      System.out.println("authenticationSuccessEvent");
    } else {
      System.out.println("not authenticationSuccessEvent");

    }
    System.out.println(authenticationSuccessEvent);
    System.out.println("Event Catched for success");
  }
}
```

result:

```
authenticationFailureEvent
org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent[source=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=use, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=false, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]]
Event Catched for Failed
authenticationSuccessEvent
org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AuthenticationSuccessEvent[source=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=user, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=F6977BE6F40E41D5972C4233868DF312], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]]
Event Catched for success
```

Comment: Still I'm unable to trigger the authentication failure event. Even after configuring the above

Comment: @vinaysaddanapu can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to I examine it? (I tested the solution before posting it)

Comment: @vinaysaddanapu where you put `@EventListener`? does spring pick the class that has the annotated method?

Comment: I have taken a separate class and added two methods and annotated with @EventListener. Able to catch authentication success event

Comment: I'm trying from my service package.

Comment: Do we need applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent("Login Failed") for Failed event also??

Comment: @vinaysaddanapu please look at the edited answer, I added the code I've done for testing

Comment: what is your Spring security version?? My version is Spring boot starter security 2.0.3v

Comment: 2.5.6 - one thing I used spring boot

Comment: Are you using applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent method??

Comment: no! the code I've posted is all I use. the rest is managed by spring